# C++ abstract variant implementation

Tags: c++, dll, abstract-class, variant

Is there any implementation of a variant like boost::ant or boost::variant, but with abstract interface, out there?

What I want is to pass variants between DLLs in a loosely coupled app. So if one DLL starts to store something new in the variant, I want to avoid changing the code of all other DLLs. All of the DLLs are build with different versions of VisualStudio with static CRT linkage, so one can't use STL classes in interfaces. Boost dependency is also undesirable. Thats why I wans an abstract interface.

If I had to implement it, I would make an **abstract interface** with functions like `MyVariantInterface::Get/SetData(int value_type_tag, byte* data) = 0`, which can be passed between DLLs safely, **plus a templated wrapper** which allows convenient storage, extraction and does all size/type checks inside the scope of one DLL.

Does something like this already exist?

Comment: Do you need one with predefined types or any number of of user defined types? E.g. QVariant from QT supports a limited amount of types only, but is probably pulling in too much if you don't depend on QT yet.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't use QT project-wide;(
User defined types are very appealing, tough a predefined-type solution is definitely worth considering too.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows you can use [VARIANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is used a lot in COM.

No extra dependencies. VARIANT supports many types including COM interfaces (e.g. IUknown). You can even pass multi dimensional arrays with it.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know a good example or documentation on this? MSDN article is somewhat cryptic.

Comment: All the functions are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762286(v=vs.85).aspx). If you have a specific question maybe you should post a new SO question.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit old now, but this kind of requirement is what COM and DCOM were designed for. That is, different versions of C/C++ and more notably different languages altogether. COM has an interface compiler which allows you to expose your classes and interfaces in an abstract manner. As egur described there is a VARIANT type which can be used to encapsulate various types. For loose coupling and late binding you might also like to consider the IDispatch interface which lets you expose your components as a call-by-name types

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDispatch

Microsoft also ships a C++ SDK for COM called ATL (Active Template Library) which is a set of useful classes that can be used to author COM components. ATL also gives you several nice wrappers to the C COM types like VARIANT and which can be used to make implementing the calling conventions and lifecycle events for COM a bit easier. Namely CComVariant for your purposes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomvariant-class?view=msvc-160

There are also some other support wrapper classes that don't rely on ATL and the one that comes to mind in your case is _variant_t

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/variant-t-class?view=msvc-160